# Shopify Buy Button JS display collection in product slider

Tags: javascript, slider, shopify

```
<div class="wrap"><div id="collection-component-1608088773387"></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  (function () {
    var scriptURL = "http://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/2.1.7/buybutton.js";
    if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
      if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
        ShopifyBuyInit();
      } else {
        loadScript();
      }
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }

    function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.async = true;
      script.src = scriptURL;
      (
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
      ).appendChild(script);
      script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
    }

    function ShopifyBuyInit() {
      var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
        storefrontAccessToken: "ACCESS TOKEN",
        domain: "xxx.myshopify.com",
        appId: "6",
      });

      var ui = ShopifyBuy.UI.init(client);

      ui.createComponent("collection", {
        id: 231614611608,
        node: document.getElementById("collection-component-1608088773387"),
        moneyFormat: "%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D",
        options: {
          product: {
            variantId: "all",
            buttonDestination: "modal",
            contents: {
              options: false,
            },
            styles: {
              product: {
                "max-width": "none",
                "margin-right": "10px",
                width: "60%",
              },
              button: {
                "background-color": "#252525",
                "font-family": "Karla",
                ":hover": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                ":focus": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              variantTitle: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              title: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
              },
              description: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              price: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              compareAt: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
            },
            googleFonts: [
              "Open Sans",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
            ],
          },
          cart: {
            contents: {
              button: true,
            },
            styles: {
              button: {
                "background-color": "#252525",
                "font-family": "Karla",
                ":hover": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                ":focus": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              footer: {
                "background-color": "#ffffff",
              },
            },
            googleFonts: ["Open Sans"],
          },
          modalProduct: {
            styles: {
              button: {
                "background-color": "#252525",
                "font-family": "Karla",
                ":hover": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                ":focus": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              variantTitle: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              title: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
              },
              description: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              price: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
              compareAt: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
            },
            googleFonts: [
              "Open Sans",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
              "PT Serif",
            ],
          },
          toggle: {
            styles: {
              toggle: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
                "background-color": "#252525",
                ":hover": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                ":focus": {
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
                "font-weight": "normal",
              },
            },
            googleFonts: ["Open Sans"],
          },
          option: {
            styles: {
              label: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
              },
              select: {
                "font-family": "Karla",
              },
            },
            googleFonts: ["PT Serif", "PT Serif"],
          },
          productSet: {
            classes: {
              products: "shopify-buy__collection-products-foo",
            },
            styles: {
              products: {
                display: "flex",
                //"display": "-webkit-flex",
                //"display": "-ms-flexbox",

                "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
                "-webkit-flex-wrap": "nowrap",
                "overflow-x": "auto",
                "-webkit-overflow-scrolling": "touch",
                "justify-content": "initial",
                "-webkit-justify-content": "initial",
                "margin-left": "0",
                "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                  "margin-left": "-20px",
                },
                "::-webkit-scrollbar": {
                  "-webkit-appearance": "none",
                  height: "8px",
                },
                "::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
                  "border-radius": "8px",
                  border: "1px solid #222222",
                  "background-color": "#222222",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      });
    }
  })();
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Hello guys, I've been searching though how to put the Shopify buy button js collection into a slider like the 2nd picture below. Anybody can enlighten me on how to do it? So far I've found code to make the products horizontally scrollable - but it isn't exactly what I want.

Currently looks like this:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Ideally what it should look like:
[image]

I had to use buy button js to get the desired modal pop up showing the product page and add to cart option everytime the user selects a product. Could someone guide me on how I can modify the code to achieved the desired result?

Comment: Are using a Shopify store?

Comment: yes, on top of that I'm using Shogun page builder from Shopify

Comment: So why buy-button JS is needed if the store is in Shopify, buy-button.js is used almost over 3rd website CMS like Wordpress?

Comment: hi onkar, there are some customisations to be done to the website itself - therefore we are choosing to use shogun on top of Shopify. The theme isn't the default from Shopify, it's built from scratch using Shogun. Shogun is almost like a drag and drop page builder. It doesn't offer to pop up modal functionality. Further customisations have to be done https://getshogun.com/help/en/articles/1391680-creating-custom-elements-with-liquid-css-and-js. My intention is to use buy button js so I can integrate it to the Shogun platform as a customised component. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I know about Shogun and make customizations also, I think you need to use vanilla JS code rather then buy-button.js to make popup and other over pages where Shogun page builder is used.

Comment: okay - sorry I'm new to shogun liquid. could you guide me on how to link the products individually to the add to cart functionality? because it's in the pop up, I'm not sure how to use vanilla js to get the individual product image, title and add to cart button (linking to the website itself so that it can process the checkout for all the items in the slider). liquid only provides product id, title and handler

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226077/discussion-between-onkar-singh-and-iblehhz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need do custom like this one

```
window.onload = () => {
  if (window.__shgProductInits.length) {
    window.__shgProductInits.forEach((ele) => {
      let proId = document.getElementById(ele.uuid);
      proId.setAttribute('url', ele.productHandle);
      proId.style.cursor='pointer';
      proId.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let productHanlde = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('url');
        fetch('/products/'+productHanlde+'.js')
          .then((Response) =>{return Response.json()})
          .then((productData) => { 
            console.log(productData);
            // now from here new logic and JS code for popup starts
          });
      });
    });
  }
}
```